# PHP Type Hinting in Method Parameter isn't working

Tags: php

Just learned about type-hinting in PHP. In my case, something is working when it shouldn't (the type hinting isn't throwing an error for invalid types).

In my project a user has selected a game and submitted it. The system invokes the relevant object, inherited from the class Game, and calls its playGame() function.

Such a game-derived class SHOULD look like this:

```
class myGame extends Game
{
    public function playGame()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The code for invoking the object:

In the system

```
// get className from user's $_POST
    ...
// invoke and pass to Player:
    require_once "classes/".$class.".class.php";
    $myObject=new $class();
    $currentPlayer->setGame($myObject); // Gives the object to the Player.
// play the game
    $currentPlayer->playGame(); // Calls Player to play the game.
```

For the Player to receive the Game, it uses the following method:

```
class Player
{
    ...
    public function setGame (Game $game) // * TYPE-HINTING.
    {
        this->game=$game;
    }
    ...
}
```

Now I tested my system with a class which happens to have the correct function, but did not inherit it -

```
class Fake
// NOT extends Game
{
    public function playGame()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

The trouble is, when you invoke the Fake class, it still works correctly - instead of throwing up an error!

Comment: Try to reformat your invoking flow in pseudo code.

Comment: According to your sample (plz add code syntax to the code in paragraph "In the system...") your code should definetly show an error. I suspect there is something else going on. Did you make sure your error reporting is working and showing ALL types of errors?

Comment: Dear ToBe,
Oh yes indeed, something else going on. Left out some syntax in my "Fake" class - now throws error like it should.
(like I said - I'm new to this).
Hey - thanks for taking the trouble to look into and answer!
Cheers!

Comment: Thanks to sectus also.
But please nobody else spend time on this - solved.